# Column value checking in NIFI

Tags: bigdata, apache-nifi

I wanted to check whether the column on my CSV file has a value or not & based on that I have to perform two separate task, any specific way to achieve that

Comment: for example split file in two smaller files using https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.14.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.QueryRecord/ and apply different processors on resulted files

Answer (score 0):

I followed [this](https://blogs.apache.org/nifi/entry/record-oriented-data-with-nifi) post and made an example

Data :

```
Id,Name,Surname
1,name1,surname1
2,name2,surname2
3,,surname3
```

Schema :

```
{"type":"record",
"name":"person",
"namespace":"any.data",
"fields":
[{"name":"Surname","type":["string"]},
{"name":"Name","type":["string"]},
{"name":"Id","type":["int"]}]}
```

Flow:

[image]

QueryRecord:

[image]

Check  [QueryRecord's usage](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.14.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.QueryRecord/additionalDetails.html)

Check [Calcite's reference](https://calcite.apache.org/docs/reference.html)